# Set Get Pointer

Tags: c++

I have this project for class that I am working on and I am not certain that I understand the question completely.  The instructions are as follows:

> When you are reading from the stream, each time you read a character the pointer is incremented by one.  That way you always get the next character. What if you want to read the same file twice?  Well you need to reset the 'get' point back to 0.  In this example, pretend that the file numbers.txt exists and that it has inside it the number 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 in order with a space in-between.  You notice that the count resets back to 1 when the get pointer is put back at the 0 location of the file.

My question is what is he asking for exactly?

Also, I am confused on what to do with int location.  Not asking to solve, just a hint in the right direction at the least.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

bool GetInputFileStream(std::ifstream * fin, std::string filename);
void SetGetPointer(std::istream & fin, int location);

int main()
{
std::ifstream fin;
    std::string filename = "numbers.txt";
    bool isOpen = GetInputFileStream(&fin, filename);
    std::cout << filename << " open: ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isOpen << std::endl;
    int number = 0;
    fin >> number;
    std::cout << "Read: " << number << std::endl;
    fin >> number;
    std::cout << "Read: " << number << std::endl;
    SetGetPointer(fin, 0);
    while (fin >> number)
    {
        std::cout << "Read: " << number << std::endl;
    }
    fin.close();

  std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue";
  std::cin.get();

}//END MAIN

bool GetInputFileStream(std::ifstream * fin, std::string filename)
{

    std::ifstream Infield(filename);
    return Infield.good();

}

void SetGetPointer(std::istream & fin, int location)
{

     &fin.seekg(std::ios::beg);

    //What am I missing with location??

}
```

Comment: The code is calling the 1-parameter version of `seekg()`, where `std::ios:beg` represents the beginning of the stream.  The `location` parameter is being ignored. The correct way to use the `location` would be to call the 2-parameter `seekg()` instead: `fin.seekg(location, std::ios_base::beg);`, which would be seek to position 0 relative to the beginning of the stream (BTW, the `&` in front of `fin.seekg()` is not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The description given by your professor is what needs to be implemented in `SetGetPointer()`

From the description: `Well you need to reset the 'get' point back to 0.`
You can see how the function is being used:
`SetGetPointer(fin, 0);`

So you can say that `SetGetPointer()` sets `fin` at a certain `location`. In the previous example, it sets `fin` back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,  it turned that I had the Bool function wrong being a large part of it.  It was getting the input from the numbers.txt file the original way I had it set up.  I should have had my Bool as:

bool GetInputFileStream(std::ifstream * fin, std::string filename)
{

```
(*fin).open(filename, std::ios::in);
return (*fin).good();
```

}

Anyway, thank you both for your help.